# Open Source Asset Management or File Server

Tags: image, repository, alassetslibrary, assets

I'm looking for a simple tool that would allow users to update and tag assets.
THen search/browse for assets and view the assets in the search results.

I have lots of files, i.e. logos, buttons, infographics, icons. I'd like to be able to share the with co-workers and have them be able to easily locate them without have to guess based on file names.

Right now I'm using apache with dir listing and htaccess. But this is less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about Version Controls? If so, [Git](http://git-scm.com/) can help.

Comment: No.. I'm looking for something that will allow me to search for assets as well a scroll throw lists of assets and view them. I currently have them backed up and versioned in github, but github won't display an image and it won't allow you to enter meta/data or search. Nor would I expect it to, it's not really intended for this...